# Storing assigned ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams and modifying them at arbitrary moments

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, android-lifecycle

I need to modify custom `View`'s `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` depending on some inner state of the `View`.

The task looks like this:

1. Set some of the `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` during `View`'s initialization at the same time saving them to keep track of what was set via `View`'s layout attributes (`layout_marginTop`, etc).
2. At the desired moments in the future, change `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` using either stored values or some other ones.

Hence, I have 2 questions:

1. **What is the right place to save `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` set via the layout attributes?**

Can't do it in the `View`'s constructor, since the parent `ViewGroup` hasn't yet assigned it. Is `onAttachedToWindow()` the correct place for that?

2. **Is `onMeasure()` the correct place for adjusting `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` as needed?**

Something like this:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)getLayoutParams();
    params.topMargin = ...;
    setLayoutParams(params);

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Since in the code above we're calling `setLayoutParams()` in `onMeasure()` (when the current layout pass in progress), would it cause the second layout pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just keep a reference to the `ViewGroup` that you're working with, and call `getLayoutParams` as needed. You'll need to make the `params` variable a more specific instance of `ViewGroup`- You could instantiate it as

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
```

Then, you can just call your choice of

```
params.setMarginStart(int);
params.setMarginEnd(int);
params.setMargins(int, int, int, int);
```

to set the margins. Note that you do NOT need to call `setLayoutParams()` at all to have the changes apply. The `params` variable and `view.getLayoutParams()` reference the same object, so any changes you make to one will apply to the other.

A full code example could look like the following:

```
public final class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RelativeLayout parent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
    }

    private void setParentMargin(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
        params.setMarginStart(left);
        params.setMarginEnd(right);
    }

}
```

As long as you call that method after `onCreate`, you should be fine.

The answer to your second question depends on what event is triggering the change in margin. If it's whenever the activity gets recreated, you could do it in `onResume` (because that's guaranteed to happen after `onCreate`). You could also call it from an `onClickListener`, or from an interface callback. So, you do not necessarily have to set the margins in `onMeasure`.

Comment: In your answer to my first question (supposing that the custom `View` is put inside a `RelatveLayout` as in your example) I don't think that `relativeLayout.getLayoutParams()` and `customView.getLayoutParams()` are the same thing. Every `View` (including a `RelatveLayout`) has its own `LayoutParams` keeping params specifically for that `View` and which could be obtained via `getLayoutParams()`. So, not sure why you're trying to manage custom `View`'s params using its parent params.

Comment: Secondly, when implementing custom `Views`, we can't rely on some `Activity` lifecycle callbacks (like `onCreate()` in your example), because `View` and `Activity` are two completely different things with their own lifecycles.

Comment: In your answer to my second question, again you're mixing `Activity` lifecycle and `View` lifecycles. Also, we don't know at what exact moment we need to change our `MarginParams`. It could be event or call from parent `View` or `Activity` or whatever else. In other words, I'm looking for 'universal' solution (proposed by the Android SDK) which is NOT tied to any assumption on 'when' it could happen.

Comment: Only `RelativeLayout` and its children can have the parameter `layout_margin`. That means your `ViewGroup` has to be of type `RelativeLayout` or your custom view has to be a child of a `RelativeLayout`.  Views also don't really have lifecycles in the same way that activities do. I think the easiest way to do what you want to achieve is to track the state of the view using its hosting activity, and change the margins with code from the activity. Not from code within your custom view. It's hard to say more without more details about what you're doing.

Comment: I see what you want to do, and I don't think that's really a route worth exploring. You can't always guarantee that the parent is going to be a `RelativeLayout`, and therefore you can't set `LayoutParams` within your custom view class.

Comment: `Only RelativeLayout and its children can have the parameter layout_margin.` That's absolutely incorrect. ANY `View` that could contain other `Views` MUST be a [`ViewGroup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) by definition. Almost (if not) every `ViewGroup` assigns its own `LayoutParams` to its children (see names of Known Subclasses sections [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)). And all known to me `ViewGroup` support `layout_margin` attribute for their children.

Comment: The answers to your questions are as follows:

1. You do not need to save that attribute manually. If you extending a class that already has it, you can get the `LayoutParams` with `getLayoutParams`. If you aren't extending a class with that, extend a class with that.

2. No. "As needed" implies that you want to do it whenever you want, and that means it should not be in a lifecycle method.

If you would like other answers, edit your question accordingly. If that did not answer your question, edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: You're still missing some of points in my question - no need to edit it for now.
1. I HAVE to save initial `LayoutParams` at least once, because they provide values which were set in attributes in `layout.xml` for my `View`. And I want to use those values later.

Comment: 2. The fact that something happens outside of **`View`'s own lifecycle** doesn't mean that it's impossible to react to those changes NOT leveraging View's lifecycle. Or. at least, as I said, I'd like to know the proposed Android way for handling this, because I frankly don't know other way than using View's lifecycle WITHOUT delegating View's internal work/responsibilities to Activity/whatever else (which is a poor design approach).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151742/discussion-between-evanklicker-and-alexander-abakumov).